# How to add count column into query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a query

```
WITH a as (
SELECT
      SECTION
    , MAX(PRICE) over w
    , MIN(PRICE) over w
    , AVG(PRICE) over w
    , TIME t, price
    , case when MAX(PRICE) over w = price then TIME end maxt
    , case when MIN(PRICE) over w = price then TIME end mint
FROM s154
WINDOW w as (partition by section)
)
select DISTINCT
      SECTION
    , MAX
    , MIN
    , AVG
    , max(maxt) over (partition by section)
    , min(mint) over (partition by section)
from a;
```

I decided to modify my table by adding new column into WITH:

```
count(*) FROM s154 GROUP BY section.
```

But adding group by clause asks for max and min in group by too. Is it possible to count sections in WITH part of the query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add `count(*) over w`:

```
WITH s as (
      SELECT SECTION, MAX(PRICE) over w as max_price,
             MIN(PRICE) over w as min_price, AVG(PRICE) over w as avg_price, 
             TIME as t, price,
             (case when MAX(PRICE) over w = price then TIME end) as maxt
             (case when MIN(PRICE) over w = price then TIME end) as mint,
             (COUNT(*) over w) as cnt
      FROM s154 WINDOW w as (partition by section)
     )
select DISTINCT SECTION, max_price, min_price, avg_price,
       max(maxt) over (partition by section),
       min(mint) over (partition by section),
       cnt
from s;
```

I'm pretty sure this query can be simplified.  I added a few things so it is easier to follow:

- Explicit column aliases.  Name your own columns, they are important.
- `as` before the column alias, so I can tell where the name is.
- Meaningful CTE name.  "a" is meaningless in this context.  At least "s" is an abbreviation for the table.

I think the simpler version is:

```
      SELECT SECTION, MAX(PRICE) as max_price,
             MIN(PRICE) as min_price, AVG(PRICE) as avg_price, 
             (ARRAY_AGG(time ORDER BY price))[1] as time_at_min_price,
             (ARRAY_AGG(time ORDER BY price DESC))[1] as time_at_max_price
      FROM s154 
      GROUP BY section;
```

This seems like a much better way to express the logic.